# How to type-overload functions with multiple optional args?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a function with multiple kwargs with defaults. One of them (in the middle somewhere) is a boolean toggle that controls the return type.

I would like to create two overloads for this method with `Literal[True/False]` but keeping the default value.

My idea was the following:

```py
from typing import overload, Literal

@overload
def x(a: int = 5, t: Literal[True] = True, b: int = 5) -> int: ...

@overload
def x(a: int = 5, t: Literal[False] = False, b: int = 5) -> str: ...

def x(a: int = 5, t: bool = True, b: int = 5) -> int | str:
    if t:
        return 5
    return "asd"
```

But mypy raises:

> error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types

I assume that is because `x()` will conflict.

But I cannot remove the default `= False` value in the second overload since it is preceded by arg `a` with a default.

How can I overload this properly such that

- `x()` → `int`
- `x(t=True)` → `int`
- `x(t=False)` → `str`

Comment: Not what you want to hear, but I would get rid of the `t` parameter and have two separate functions, each with a single return type.

Comment: @mkrieger1 while that would solve this toy problem. I just want to add typing to a fairly known package that is untyped at the moment and changing the interface only due to typing issues is out of the question :)

Comment: Note that the function signatures in your examples are just arguments, not necessarily keyword arguments. So title should read "with multiple optional arguments" instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an old problem. The reason is that you specify default value in both branches, so `x()` is possible in both and return type is undefined.

I have the following pattern for such cases:

```py
from typing import overload, Literal

@overload
def x(a: int = ..., t: Literal[True] = True, b: int = ...) -> int: ...

@overload
def x(a: int = ..., *, t: Literal[False], b: int = ...) -> str: ...

@overload
def x(a: int, t: Literal[False], b: int = ...) -> str: ...

def x(a: int = 5, t: bool = True, b: int = 1) -> int | str:
    if t:
        return 5
    return "asd"
```

Why and how? You have to think about ways to call your function. First, you can provide `a`, then `t` can be given as kwarg (#2) or arg (#3). You can also leave `a` default, then `t` is always a kwarg (#2 again). This is needed to prevent putting arg after kwarg, which is `SyntaxError`. Overloading on more than one parameter is more difficult, but possible this way too:

```
@overload
def f(a: int = ..., b: Literal[True] = ..., c: Literal[True] = ...) -> int: ...

@overload
def f(a: int = ..., *, b: Literal[False], c: Literal[True] = ...) -> Literal['True']: ...

@overload
def f(a: int = ..., *, b: Literal[False], c: Literal[False]) -> Literal['False']: ...

@overload
def f(a: int, b: Literal[False], c: Literal[True] = ...) -> Literal['True']: ...

@overload
def f(a: int, b: Literal[False], c: Literal[False]) -> Literal['False']: ...

def f(a: int = 1, b: bool = True, c: bool = True) -> int | Literal['True', 'False']:
    return a if b else ('True' if c else 'False')  # mypy doesn't like str(c)
```

You can play with overloading [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=8cb62c8b34a329369db31d7ec524c37c).

Ellipsis (`...`) in overloaded signatures default values means "Has a default, see implementation for its value". It is no different from the actual value for the type checker, but makes your code saner (default values are defined only in actual signatures and not repeated).

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense for overloads to have default values, and you *can* remove the defaults from the literal argument as long as you also remove the defaults from the other arguments.

```
@overload
def x(a: int | None, t: Literal[True], b: int | None ) -> int: ...

@overload
def x(a: int | None, t: Literal[False], b: int | None ) -> str: ...
```